# Get data nested in array with firebase

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble getting data in my chat web app from Firebase.
I am using Firebase functions and typescript.

I have stored some information about the sender and the recipient in my chat object like so:

```
chats: {
   :chatId: {
       users: {
          userNames: ["senderName", "recipientName"]
          userIds: ["senderId", "recipientId"]
       }
   }
}
```

Now, I am trying to write a function that retrieves all the chats where the userId of the user that make the request is stored in the userIds object.

My typescript functions looks like that:

```
export const getUserChats=functions.https.onRequest((req:PR_UserRequest, res: Response) => {

    let chatsData: DocumentData[] = [];

    db.collection("chats").where("usersIds", "array-contains", `${req.user?.userId}`).get()
        .then((chats) => {

            chats.forEach((doc) => chatsData.push(doc.data()))
            res.json(chatsData);

        })
})
```

Result:

```
[]
```

I am fetching the chats collection and filtering it whit the where method, but it seems not founding the userIds array. In fact that function returns an empty "chats" array.

Expected result:

```
{
    users: {
        userNames: ["senderName", "recipientName"]
        userIds: ["senderId", "recipientId"]
    }
    ...other data
}
```

What should I do to retrive the correct result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hey @Francesco Bollini , please correct me if I'm wrong. you have a collection here called "chats" which has documents with chatid and inside every document there is users object. this users object has two properities userNames and userIds and you want to create a function that get all the chats that the caller has a record in those chats no?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to have exactly that result.

Comment: As I can see you are trying to filter by "userIds" which is not a field in your chatId document and that's not possible in firestore as you can filter only by fields. so here you can filter only by "users" field. The only thing that you can do in your current data schema is to fetch all the chats and filter on the frontend. Other thing you can do is change your schema so it can suit your use case i.e your chatid document should have users fields which is an array of user ids and this way you can use "array-contains" method to fetch only the documents that contains this userid

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please accept it if it helps solves your issue. This will help the communti also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you are trying to filter by "userIds" which is not a field in your chatId document and that's not possible in firestore as you can filter only by fields. so here you can filter only by "users" field. The only thing that you can do in your current data schema is to fetch all the chats and filter on the frontend. Other thing you can do is change your schema so it can suit your use case i.e your chatid document should have users fields which is an array of user ids and this way you can use "array-contains" method to fetch only the documents that contains this userid